# Is there a way to query for structure Entries that have no Parent?

Tags: craft3, structure, elementquery

Suppose I have a structure Section with Entries like this:

- Parent A

  - Child X
- Parent B
- Parent C

  - Child Y

How would I return this list of Entries?

```
[Parent A, Parent B, Parent C]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `level()` parameter ([docs](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/entries.html#level)) on your query:

```twig
{% set entries = craft.entries()
    .section('yourSectionHandle')
    .level(1)
    .all() %}
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Oli. I really appreciate your help. Thank you again.